# Why my input field is Unexpected end. After PHP string concatenation?

Tags: javascript, php, function

In my PHP code, I `echo`  a string that contains an input field with a javascript event. In this event, I assign a function where we pass 2 arguments. One is a number an another is a string.

Some this is wrong with my concatenation in function arguments. When I click on the input field I got this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

---

**Here is my code:-**

```
<?php
$id = 6;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<?php
echo '<input type="checkbox" data-plugin-iso-switchx onchange="smtp_function('.$id.', "dfgdfg")">';
?>

<script>
    function smtp_function(a, b){
        alert('ok');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with the `"` quotes inside the javascript part. Try this:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" data-plugin-iso-switchx onchange="smtp_function('.$id.', \'dfgdfg\')">';
```

Here I use `'` quotes instead of `"` and I escape them with a backslash.

In case the `$id` is not numeric it also needs quotes. You can do this to add those quotes:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" data-plugin-iso-switchx onchange="smtp_function(\''.$id.'\', \'dfgdfg\')">';
```

All these quotes can become quite unreadable, so it might be better to use this:

```
$js = "smtp_function('$id', 'dfgdfg')";
echo '<input type="checkbox" data-plugin-iso-switchx onchange="'.$js.'">';
```

Note that variables inside double quotes are evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use twice ".

Try changing the type of quotation marks or using escape characters

I prefer to use ` when it is a text string because it does not interrupt line breaks

The following code works.

```
<?php
$id = 6;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<?php
echo '<input type="checkbox" data-plugin-iso-switchx onchange="smtp_function('.$id.', `dfgdfg`)">';
?>

<script>
    function smtp_function(a, b){
        alert('ok');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this can help you.